# Representation of Android Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-security

In my app I am simply reading SMS inbox and Call Log. Hence I have added the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

But when I go to the phone's Permission Control, it shows all of the following with respect to READ_SMS.

1. Read SMS
2. Read MMS
3. Send MMS
4. Send Email

While #1 and #2 are fine, I do not understand why #3 and #4 are shown as well. I am not using SEND_SMS permission and in my code I am not sending SMS anywhere. This will give a wrong impression to users.

The READ_CALL_LOG permission is being shown properly. Issue is only with READ_SMS.

Any idea anyone?

[image]

Comment: Android does not have a "Permission Control" screen like the one you describe. What version of Android is this device running?

Comment: I am testing on a Lenovo phone running on Android 5.1.

Comment: Permissions are managed by groups. So it's a normal behavior even if we don't like it.

Comment: With Android 6.0's runtime permissions overhaul, I would expect to see this sort of behavior, as users' control over permissions is really more at the group level. We have no good way of telling you how Lenovo is electing to build their "Permission Control" app. You would be better served using other techniques, such as examining your overall app's manifest (e.g., `build/intermediates/manifests/...` in your Android Studio module), or `aapt dump badging`, to confirm exactly what permissions you are requesting.

Comment: Okay understood. Thank you @greywolf82 for the explanation!

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I understood the point. Also, I checked the manifest file inside build/intermediates/manifests and over there also it is same READ_SMS only.

Comment: My best guess is that Lenovo is showing everything in the permission group. I am not quite certain why.

Comment: Okay. I will try to test it out in some other manufacturer phone. So are you saying that this "Permission Control" is usually not present at all in most models (prior to 6.0)?